# How to design a server with many persistent connections

Tags: java, sockets, client, persistent-connection

I am designing a application where many clients connect to a central server. This server keeps these connections, sending keep-alives every half-hour. The server has a embedded HTTP server, which provides a interface to the client connections (ex. http://server/isClientConnected?id=id). I was wondering what is the best way to go about this. My current implementation is in Java, and I just have a Map with ID's as the key, but a thread is started for each connection, and I don't know if this is really the best way to do this. Any pointers would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Isaac Waller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the java.nio package, as described on this page: [Building Highly Scalable Servers with Java NIO](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/09/01/nio.html). Also read this page very carefully: [Architecture of a Highly Scalable NIO-Based Server](http://today.java.net/cs/user/print/a/350).

Personally I'd not bother with the NIO internals and use a framework like [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/) or [xSocket](http://xsocket.sourceforge.net/). NIO is complicated and easy to get wrong in very obscure ways. If you want it to "just work", then use a framework.

Answer (score 3):

With a single thread per connection you can usually scale up to about 10,000 connections on a single machine.  For a Windows 32 machine, you probably will hit a limit around 1,000 connections.

To avoid this, you can either change the design of your program, or you can scale out (horizontal).  You have to weight the cost of development with the cost of hardware.

The single thread per user, with a single continuous connection is usually the easiest programming model.  I would stick with this model until you reach the limits of your current hardware.  At that point, I would decide to either change the code, or add more hardware.

Answer (score 2):

If the clients will be connected for long periods of time, allocating a thread per client can be problematic. Each thread on the server requires a certain amount of resources (memory for the stack, for example).

You could use [Jetty Continuations](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Features/Continuations) to handle the client request with fewer threads by using asynchronous servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Read more about the the Reactor pattern. There is an implementation for that in Java (it uses channels instead of thread for client). 
It is easy to implement and very efficient.